Unable to provide input parameter "Evalue" using selenium in python on a web page
I intend to write a script which browse a web page from chrome with the following link:
https://isfinder.biotoul.fr/  from which i have to select "TOOLS" dropdown menu and then select "Blast". I also manage to upload file in which is in fasta format but then under the heading "Algorithm parameters" I want to change parameter Evalue : 0.01 and then run blast which I am unable to do ! Please guide me what I am doing wrong, what I should do to achive the same.
I have written a python code to achieve the same but don't work.
 # Necessary webdrivers need to be imported
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
import time

# This is for Chrome. Similarly if

# Firefox is needed, then it has to be specified
webBrowser = webdriver.Chrome()

# This will open Is finder site in chrome
webBrowser.get('https://www-is.biotoul.fr/index.php')

# Find and click on the 'TOOLS' link
tools_link = WebDriverWait(webBrowser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'TOOLS')))
tools_link.click()

# Find and click on the 'Blast' link
blast_link = WebDriverWait(webBrowser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Blast')))
blast_link.click()

# Locate and interact with form elements
file_input = WebDriverWait(webBrowser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")))
file_input.send_keys("/Users/somil/Desktop/gene_bank.file/TA373.fasta")


# Enter job title
job_title_input = WebDriverWait(webBrowser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input")))
job_title_input.send_keys("TA373")

######till here it works ###########

#Evalue put
evalue_input = WebDriverWait(webBrowser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='Evalue']")))

# Clear existing value if any and set the new value
evalue_input.clear()
evalue_input.send_keys("0.01")

Please remember I am new to python !
Thanks in advance.

Issue is in this XPath expression - //input[@name='Evalue']. This is not locating any element.
The correct XPath to locate desired element is - //input[@name='expect']
Change the code as below:
evalue_input = WebDriverWait(webBrowser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='expect']")))

UPDATE: Check the below image of desired HTML element(input textbox). You will notice the value of name attribute is expect and not Evalue.


Sorry it didn't work still i am unable to change the value from 10.0 to 0.01 but I am curious how did you locate where desired element is ?

I tested it and it's working for me. When you say its still not working for you, what error do you see now in your console? Check the updated answer to your question about finding desired element.

It didn't throw any error on my console but it did close unexpectedly so i add time.sleep(60) but it still didn't work as expected.

Where did you add time.sleep(60)? Add it after this line evalue_input.send_keys("0.01") and notice if the value changes to 0.01 on the page.

I added time.sleep(60)  just before this command evalue_input = WebDriverWait(webBrowser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='expect']"))) after your suggestion it works. Thank you

Can you please also tell what had happened when i add time.sleep(60) before and after the command?

time.sleep(60) means it will blindly wait for 60 seconds. It is not needed at all. Your code is working fine without it. I asked you to add it at the end just so that you can see the value being changed to 0.01. Otherwise the program executes so fast and closes the browser even before you could see it. Hope this helps.
